NextJs 13 migration from page router to app router, Implement default browser back
We are currently using NextJs 13 page router. We want to migrate to app router from page router to enhance the performance.
In the current _app.js, we have a handler which redirects to logout page on click of browser back button. The code looks like below:
const MainApp = ({ router }) => {

  const handleBackButtonClick = () => {
    router.beforePopState(() => {
      redirectToLogout(router);
      return false;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   
    handleBackButtonClick();
  }, []);
 ...

In order to implement the same functionality in app router. I tried using useRouter from next/router in the layout.js but it gave me below error:
'NextRouter' was not mounted. After going through the documentation, I got to know that we should be using router from next/navigation but beforePopState isn't available in this router.
I tried adding popstate event handler on window but that also did not work
 useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopState = (event) => {
      // Your custom logic to handle back button behavior
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default navigation (optional)

      // Optionally, perform custom navigation or actions here
      router.push('/previous-page'); // Example: Navigate to a specific page
    };

    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState); // Clean up
    };
  }, [router]);

I am stuck on this one from quite a long. Has anyone faced similar issues with app router of nextJs 13?
